# Trouble trying to fix UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I'm 100% new to iOS development and the sole developer for a project I inherited from some contractors, so I'm at a loss for how to figure out the cause of this issue.

I was able to expand out the output log for more verbose details and I was sort of able to track down the view, but I can't seem to find the exact component it is referring to.

```
UIWindow:0x7f98ce414290
|   UILayoutContainerView:0x7f98ce512ad0
|   |   UINavigationTransitionView:0x7f98ce428970
|   |   |   UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x7f98ce42b220
|   |   |   |   SWRevealView:0x7f98ce50b0e0
|   |   |   |   |   UIView:0x7f98ce50abd0
|   |   |   |   |   |   UILayoutContainerView:0x7f98ce50dfb0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   UINavigationTransitionView:0x7f98ce614110
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x7f98ce407440
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •UIView:0x7f98ce622790, MISSING HOST CONSTRAINTS
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x600003aef720 - "UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide", layoutFrame = {{0, 20}, {414, 716}}, owningView = <UIView: 0x7f98ce622790; frame = (0 0; 414 736); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000d08030>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000003d19a0>>>- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UILayoutGuide:0x600003aef720'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.Width{id: 295}, UILayoutGuide:0x600003aef720'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.Height{id: 290}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f98ce621cf0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f98ce61e450
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f98ce622970
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •UIView:0x7f98d1703b40
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x600003a997a0 - "UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide", layoutFrame = {{0, 0}, {320, 89.666666666666671}}, owningView = <UIView: 0x7f98d1703b40; frame = (0 0; 320 50); autoresize = W+H; tag = 10; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000385d60>>>- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UILayoutGuide:0x600003a997a0'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.Height{id: 391}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x7f98ce51a5d0- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UIButton:0x7f98ce51a5d0.minY{id: 404}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x7f98ce436990
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *APP_NAME.CustomLabel:0x7f98ce6291f0'School Details'- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for APP_NAME.CustomLabel:0x7f98ce6291f0'School Details'.minY{id: 406}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x7f98d1704b20- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UIButton:0x7f98d1704b20.minY{id: 432}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f98d1700000- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UIView:0x7f98d1700000.minY{id: 411}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *APP_NAME.CustomLabel:0x7f98ce628890
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x7f98ce628660
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UICollectionView:0x7f98cf81fa00
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f98ce616e90
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIStackView:0x7f98ce617070
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x7f98ce6101a0'NOT INTERESTED'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x7f98ce60f7e0'APPLY NOW (0)'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f98ce6107e0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f98ce621b10
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x7f98ce621090
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f98ce6212c0'Thank you for signing up ...'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x7f98ce620cb0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f98ce61cf60
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x7f98ce61c560
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f98ce620270'Hang Tight!

There are no...'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *APP_NAME.CustomButton:0x7f98ce6104c0'REFRESH'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f98ce60be10
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x7f98ce613340
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x7f98d11144a0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f98ce621ed0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f98ce6220b0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x7f98ce622290
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   UINavigationBar:0x7f98d3804100
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   _UIBarBackground:0x7f98d3804520
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x7f98d38049b0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIVisualEffectView:0x7f98d3804be0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   _UIVisualEffectBackdropView:0x7f98ce61fdf0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   _UIVisualEffectSubview:0x7f98ce612760
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   _UINavigationBarLargeTitleView:0x7f98d3805430
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UILabel:0x7f98ce50b310
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •_UINavigationBarContentView:0x7f98d3805010
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x600003a88000 - "BackButtonGuide(0x7f98d38052d0)", layoutFrame = {{0, 0}, {12, 44}}, owningView = <_UINavigationBarContentView: 0x7f98d3805010; frame = (0 0; 414 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000003b8840>>>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x600003a880e0 - "LeadingBarGuide(0x7f98d38052d0)", layoutFrame = {{12, 0}, {36, 44}}, owningView = <_UINavigationBarContentView: 0x7f98d3805010; frame = (0 0; 414 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000003b8840>>>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x600003a881c0 - "TitleView(0x7f98d38052d0)", layoutFrame = {{48, 0}, {354, 44}}, owningView = <_UINavigationBarContentView: 0x7f98d3805010; frame = (0 0; 414 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000003b8840>>>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x600003a882a0 - "TrailingBarGuide(0x7f98d38052d0)", layoutFrame = {{402, 0}, {0, 44}}, owningView = <_UINavigationBarContentView: 0x7f98d3805010; frame = (0 0; 414 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000003b8840>>>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x600003a88380 - "UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide", layoutFrame = {{20, 20}, {374, 24}}, owningView = <_UINavigationBarContentView: 0x7f98d3805010; frame = (0 0; 414 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000003b8840>>>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f98d110a480
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutGuide: 0x600003a94540 - "UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide", layoutFrame = {{0, 0}, {36, 44}}, owningView = <_UIButtonBarStackView: 0x7f98d110a480; frame = (12 0; 36 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000003e9680>>>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f98ce40f9d0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *_UIModernBarButton:0x7f98ce42fdc0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x7f98ce4357d0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   _UINavigationBarModernPromptView:0x7f98ce50b600

Legend:
    * - is laid out with auto layout
    + - is laid out manually, but is represented in the layout engine because translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES
    • - layout engine host

2019-09-02 08:36:02.740049+0900 APP_NAME[87051:13418262] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000020c8370 UIView:0x7f98d1700000.height == 0.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000020d30c0 APP_NAME.CustomLabel:0x7f98ce628890.height == 19   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000020d1f90 UIImageView:0x7f98ce628660.height == 50   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000020c8730 V:[UIView:0x7f98d1700000]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f98d1703b40 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000020c87d0 V:[APP_NAME.CustomLabel:0x7f98ce628890]-(>=5)-[UIView:0x7f98d1700000]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000020c8870 UIImageView:0x7f98ce628660.top == UILayoutGuide:0x600003a997a0'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.top + 10   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000020c8960 V:[UIImageView:0x7f98ce628660]-(5)-[APP_NAME.CustomLabel:0x7f98ce628890]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002084b90 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7f98d1703b40.height == 50   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000020c84b0 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-top' V:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600003a997a0'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f98d1703b40 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000020d1f90 UIImageView:0x7f98ce628660.height == 50   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

For example, I can find `UIView:0x7f98d1703b40`, but I can't the custom label it is referring to.

Any and all help is appreciated :-/

***** **EDIT** *****

I finally was able to track it down to this line of code that adds a navigation bar to the UIView:0x7f98ce622790. If I comment it out, the error goes away, but the navbar is gone.

```
extension DIBaseController: NavigationDelegate {

    func configureNavigtion(onView view: UIView, title: String?,chatTitle: String? = nil,chatImage: String? = nil, leftButtonAction leftAction: ButtonAction = .back, rightButoonTitle: String? = "" , rightButtonAction:ButtonAction = .hidden ) {
        view.backgroundColor = .clear

        let navBar = NavigationBar()
        addChildViewController(navBar)
        navBar.view.frame = view.bounds
        navBar.view.tag = 10

        // THIS IS THE LINE THAT CAUSES THE PROBLEM
        view.addSubview(navBar.view)

        navBar.configureNavigation(title,chatTitle,chatImage,leftButtonAction: leftAction,rightButoonTitle:rightButoonTitle,rightButtonAction:rightButtonAction)
        navBar.delegate = self
    }

    @objc func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: NavigationBar,leftButtonTapped leftButton: UIButton) {
        switch navigationBar.leftAction {
        case .back:
            navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            break
        case .hidden,.menu:
            break
        default: break
        }
    }

    @objc func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: NavigationBar,rightButtonTapped rightButton: UIButton){
    }
}
```

The NavigationBar class looks like this.

```
protocol NavigationDelegate {
    func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: NavigationBar,leftButtonTapped leftButton: UIButton)
    func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: NavigationBar,rightButtonTapped rightButton: UIButton)
}

enum ButtonAction {

    case back
    case hidden
    case menu
    case chat
    case option

    var icon: UIImage? {
        switch self {
        case .back: return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "back_Arrow")
        case .hidden : return nil
        case .menu: return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "menu")
        case .chat: return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "chatt")
        case .option : return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_chart_more")
        }
    }
}

import UIKit
class NavigationBar: UIViewController {


    //MARK:-IBOulets.
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var chatUserTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var leftButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var chatUserImage: UIImageView!


    //MARK:-Variables.
    var delegate:NavigationDelegate?
    var leftAction:ButtonAction = .back
    var rightAction:ButtonAction = .hidden


    //MARK:-ViewLifeCycle.
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Methods
    //MARK: ... Public
    func configureNavigation(_ title: String? = nil, _ chatTitle: String? = nil, _ chatImage: String? = nil,leftButtonAction leftAction: ButtonAction = .back,rightButoonTitle: String?,rightButtonAction: ButtonAction = .hidden) {
        setupAppearance(on: leftButton, withAction: leftAction)
        self.leftAction = leftAction
        if let url = chatImage ,url != "" {
       self.chatUserImage.isHidden = false
            self.chatUserImage.kf.setImage(with:  URL(string:url), placeholder: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user_profile"), options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: nil)
        }else {
            self.chatUserImage.isHidden = true
            self.chatUserImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user_profile")
        }
        self.titleLabel.text = title
        self.chatUserTitle.text = chatTitle


        if rightButoonTitle == "" {
            rightButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
            setupAppearance(on: rightButton, withAction: rightButtonAction)
            //rightButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }else{
          rightButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
          rightButton.setTitle(rightButoonTitle, for: .normal)
        }


    }

    func setupAppearance(on button: UIButton, withAction action: ButtonAction) -> Void {
        if action == .hidden {
           button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }else{
           button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
        button.setImage(action.icon, for: UIControlState())
    }


    // MARK:- IBActions Methods
    @IBAction func leftButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {
        delegate?.navigationBar(self, leftButtonTapped: sender)
    }
    @IBAction func rightButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.navigationBar(self, rightButtonTapped: sender)
    }

}
```

Comment: `    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000020d1f90 UIImageView:0x7f98ce628660.height == 50   (active)>"` is the spot where you've got the issue. I'd do something like adjust the priority of the constraint down a little and see if that fixes it.

Comment: You need to show the code (and / or the Storyboard layout) you are using to configure the view.

Comment: Updated. Also, I tried doing that Adrian suggested, but once I lowered the priority, then 5 new errors popped up. I also tried removing some, but that just breaks the code and other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion Adrian and much appreciation for the explanation cesl.

In order to fix it, I had to change the priority of the constraints on the NavigationBar. However, since there is no storyboard for it and it's done programmatically (I assume it's a native component), I had to loop through all the constraints and change it's priority to something low, like 200.

```
for constraint in navBar.view.constraints {
   constraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(200)
}
```

This allows me to keep the constraints in place, while letting the auto layout thing resize the components as needed and keeping the UI from destroying itself like it would if I just removed them.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand properly, `UIView:0x7f98d1700000`, `APP_NAME.CustomLabel:0x7f98ce628890` and `UIImageView:0x7f98ce628660` are inside `UIView:0x7f98d1703b40`. the image height is set to 50, it has 10 from the top and 5 to the label, the label height is set to 19, if you sum that to get an idea of the height of the content you get 84 at least, but the container view's height is only 50 (0x7f98d1703b40) .

The log is telling you that 84 doesn't fit in 50, so, it has to remove a constraint to try to fix the error.

`Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000020d1f90 UIImageView:0x7f98ce628660.height == 50   (active)>`

Which leads the image to have a height different than 50. If you are ok with it you can use the solution from Adrian.

If not, you could increase the height of the container view, or decrease the height of the content, the solution will depend on what you want to achieve.